# Validating prices use regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js

I'm trying to validate an input with regEx in Vue, which I don't have any idea how to make one and couldn't find online how to match what I want to do.

The thing is I'm trying to validate a price that should be a float with 2 decimal numbers, and it can be 1 number before the . or 9 digits. For example:

```
0.50 

1.00

99999.99

999999999.00
```

I tried this:

```
v => (/\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*(?:[.,]\d{2})/.test(v))
```

But doesn't work.

Sorry if my english is not very good. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Doesn't work in which way? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . The regex will likely match but it's faulty and allows for non-numeric input

Comment: IMHO there is nothing unclear about this question.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Perhaps. Maybe you'd like to improve the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match 1-9 digits before the dot, and 2 decimal numbers:

```
^\d{1,9}\.\d{1,2}$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/LTzLX1/1).

Answer (score 1):

What do you want? Check the value for matching a number from 0 to 999999999 in the integer part and no more than 2 numbers after "."?

A template assuming that the entire string being checked from the beginning (^) to the end ($) consists of

- mandatory initial part, which is either 0 or contains from 1 to 9 digits, and does not start with "0" ;
- optional ending of "." and two digits:

  ^([1-9]\d{0,8}|0)(.\d{1,2})?$